# Body border with fullscreen image inside

Tags: html, css, position

I would like to achieve a website which has a white border / space between the browser and the content of the website.

Inside of the website, there is an image which is 100% in width and height and it should adapt itself on every window size.

Like this: [image]

I could achieve it with a div (which contains the image) and set it to:

```
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
left: 15px;
right: 15px;
bottom: 15px;
```

But I am not sure if this approach is the best and most reliable. I would like to hear your thoughts and maybe some tips.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you just add a `15px` border or margin to your `body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 20px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div>Image</div>
```